# GCC problem - invalid conversion from 'void (*)(MyObject*, bool)' to 'const void*'

Tags: c++, pointers, gcc, com

I really don't want to, but I **have to emulate COM logic** in my program and I'm using standard COM_ADDREF macros, but I keep getting the following error: **invalid conversion from 'void (*)(MyObject*, bool)' to 'const void*'**... What should I do?

```
#define COM_ADDREF(pObj, pMaster) ((pObj)->AddRef((pMaster), __FILE__, __LINE__, pObj))

class BaseComObject
{
public:
    inline DWORD AddRef (const void* pMaster, const char* pFileName, int line, const void* pObj) const
    {
        iRefCount++;
        return iRefCount;
    };

    inline DWORD GetRefCount() const
    {
        return iRefCount;
    };

private:
    long iRefCount;
};

class MyObject: public BaseComObject { };

void test (MyObject* pObject, bool bValue)
{
    if (pObject)
    {
        COM_ADDREF (pObject, bValue);// error: invalid conversion from 'void (*)(MyObject*, bool)' to 'const void*'
    }
}
```

**error: invalid conversion from 'void (*)(MyObject*, bool)' to 'const void*'**

**error: initializing argument 1 of 'DWORD BaseComObject::AddRef(const void*, const char*, int, const void*) const'**

Comment: DId you try explicit cast? Like: `COM_ADDREF ( (void*)pObject, bValue);`

Comment: Are you sure that's the code that's causing that error? Your code does have a similar error (trying to convert `bool bValue` to `const void* pMaster`), but the error implies you're using a function, not a `bool`, as the second argument of `COM_ADDREF`.

Comment: @Kiril: that would be `COM_ADDREF(pObject, (void*)bValue)` if you simply want to make it compile; however, casting a `bool` to a pointer is almost certainly going to go horribly wrong (and wouldn't work anyway if, as the error message implies, it's actually a function rather than a `bool`).

Comment: @Mike Seymour - yep, you're right about "certainly going to go horribly wrong", but the point here is "certainly" :) For example, `mysql_option` function works (almost) this way (from the MySQL lib).

Comment: Thank you very much, guys! The problem was actually caused by the second parameter, which also was an object (I'm sorry, to say, but I made a mistake by specifying the boolean type...), which I had to cast to void* in order to fix the problem. I sure wish GCC would report more readable errors...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look to me like this is the code that's generating that error. When I compile it with g++ (fixing the obvious errors like DWORD and modifying class state in a `const` function, it just tells me it can't find a matching function.

The gist is you're passing a bool as the second argument to `COM_ADDREF` and the base class `AddRef` function actually wants a `void*` in that parameter position. I highly suspect you have a class with an implicit `bool` constructor you aren't showing us, and that's really confusing the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Are you posting the same code you compiled?

The error message "invalid conversion from `void (*)(MyObject*, bool)` ... " clearly refers to the (address of the) function `void test (MyObject* pObject, bool bValue)` in this example. But you don't refer to `test` on the line that should have the error.

Answer (score 0):

Function pointers such as `void ()(MyObject, bool)` and data pointers such as `void *` are not guaranteed to be the same size (certainly not by the C standard; I assume not by the C++ standard either).  POSIX does grant that guarantee, but the language standards do not.

Sometimes, you can get around the problem with a union:

```
union DataFunction
{
    void  *data;
    void (*function)();
};
```

You can assign to the function member and read from the data member and even though the standard does not guarantee that will work, unless `sizeof(void *) != sizeof(void (*)())`, it will work in practice.

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted does not match the description/messages you provided. I highly doubt one can get these error message from this code.

You code makes an obvious attempt to pass a `bool` argument for a `const void *` parameter, which is indeed an error: you are passing `bool bValue` argument as `const void* pMaster` parameter to `AddRef`. But the diagnostic message for this error should be completely different.

My guess is that you posted wrong code.

BTW, the part of COM logic you are trying to emulate (at least so far) is called *reference counting*. It has a value of its own, not attached specifically to COM. You can find quite a few examples of well-implemented reference counting in C++ on the Net.